# how to stop my program to execute after reaching certain condition?

Tags: ios, swift

It is little bit hard to explain, but I need to stop my program if reach certain condition. here is the simplified code I use

```
func getNotificationData() {

    NetworkingService.fetchJSON(url: url, methodUsed: .post, parameters: parameters) { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .failure:
            // show alert error
        case .success(let jsonFromServer):

            let json = jsonFromServer as! JSON
            let validity = json["valid"].intValue

            if validity == 0 {
                // show alert
            } else if validity == 1 {
                guard let dataNotification = json["data"].arrayObject as? [[String:Any]] else {return}

                self.notificationData = dataNotification

                self.notificationData = nil <--- HARD CODED to test empty data

                print("xxx")
                guard let notificationData = self.notificationData else {
                    print("bbbbbb")
                    self.noNotificationLabel.isHidden = false
                    self.tableView.isHidden = true
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    return
                }

                if notificationData.isEmpty {
                    self.noNotificationLabel.isHidden = false
                    self.tableView.isHidden = true
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    return
                }

                print("yyyyy")
                self.thereIsAnError = false
                print("zzzz")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to refactor my code to improve readability. I want to move some part of the code above to a function like the code below

```
func checkIfNotificationIsAvailable() {

        guard let notificationData = notificationData else {
            print("bbbbbb")
            noNotificationLabel.isHidden = false
            tableView.isHidden = true
            return
        }

        if notificationData.isEmpty {
            noNotificationLabel.isHidden = false
            tableView.isHidden = true
            return
        }
    }
```

so I expect my end code will be like this

```
func getNotificationData() {

    NetworkingService.fetchJSON(url: url, methodUsed: .post, parameters: parameters) { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .failure:

        // show alert error

        case .success(let jsonFromServer) :

            let json = jsonFromServer as! JSON
            let validity = json["valid"].intValue

            if validity == 0 {
                // show alert
            } else if validity == 1 {
                guard let dataNotification = json["data"].arrayObject as? [[String:Any]] else {return}

                self.notificationData = dataNotification

                self.notificationData = [] <--- HARD CODED to test empty data
                print("xxx")
                self.checkIfNotificationIsAvailable()
                print("yyyyy")
                print("zzzz")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but if Run the app after refactor, in the debugging Area it will print

1. xxxxx
2. yyyyy
3. zzzzzz

I expect the yyyy and zzzz will not be printed, in other word my program will stop after print("bbbbb"), in the line `if notificationData.isEmpty` , so how do I stop the program in order to stop `print("yyyy")` and `print("zzzz")` to be executed ? I thought that It can be done by using `return` but it still execute the code below `checkIfNotificationIsAvailable()`

Comment: add "return" where you want to stop

Comment: Note that mobile apps don't usually stop by themselves, it's a bad pattern to just terminate the app, it's bad UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the

```
func checkIfNotificationIsAvailable() {
...
 }
```

to return Bool

```
func checkIfNotificationIsAvailable() -> Bool{
 guard let notificationData = notificationData else {
  print("bbbbbb")

    noNotificationLabel.isHidden = false
    tableView.isHidden = true
    return true
}

if notificationData.isEmpty {


    noNotificationLabel.isHidden = false
    tableView.isHidden = true
    return false
}
 return true
}
```

and inside the function func getNotificationData() {..}

change the

```
self.checkIfNotificationIsAvailable()
```

to

```
if self.checkIfNotificationIsAvailable(){
  print("yyyyy")
  print("zzzz")
}
```

Comment: Why would you have `if (self.checkIfNotificationIsAvailable() == true){` instead of just `if self.checkIfNotificationIsAvailable(){`?

Comment: No reason it's the same